# Drag and Drop files from Applet to Desktop

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, applet

I was wondering how to drag and drop files from a java applet to the desktop. So far i've been able to display all the files with the right icon and name, but I have no clue on how to implement dragging and dropping. BTW I am a noob so it would be great if you could explain things in detail.

Comment: I think java applets have very little or no d&d support.

Comment: Ty for the response, is there a software or programming language like java that can implement drag and drop in an applet or something like an applet?

Comment: Applets is fine for d&d, however you might need the permissions to do so.

Comment: *"you might need the permissions to do so"*  Correct in part, but instead *"you **need** the permissions to do so"* - remove the 'might', emphasise 'need'.  The applet would need to be digitally signed by the developer, and trusted by the end user (when prompted), in order to do D&D.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at the Java site tutorials: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html

Comment: Looks like everything I need is in the tutorial, ty

Comment: Np, tick this question as the answer if it answers your question :)